# Select Type name in Orc.Logviewer

Tags: c#, catel

The logger control takes a `Type` as a parameter which can be used to filter logs i.e.

```
private static ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(string));
```

This would in turn add `System.String` as an option i.e. (where `IoHelperMethods` would be)

[image]

I want to be able to put custom strings in there as I can be more descriptive but unfortunately you cannot do something like:

```
private static ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example Error Filter Type");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the type as string in Catel 5:

https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/develop/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.Shared/Logging/Log.cs#L38

Isn't LogViewer correctly picking that up? If not, please create a ticket in the GitHub repro and it will be fixed.

Comment: I was using 4.5.4, I upgraded to 5.0 and the option has now become available to me. I set the logger to "private static ILog _directoryLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("dir");" for the sake of testing but the type filter is not appearing correctly - http://prntscr.com/h0j91o whereas if I revert it back to the type of my class I see http://prntscr.com/h0j9hf . This doesn't seem to behaving correctly or possibly my understanding of how it works is incorrect? What are your thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I should mention I'm trying to create "type names" in this case the type "dir" and the method I'm trying to do this is a Get method.. ("GetLogger") which is why I think my understanding may be incorrect. I want to be able to select a type of issue ie. "Windows errors" that I have defined in code

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a thing that still needs implementing in Orc.LogViewer. Raise a ticket and it will be taken care of.